# Scrolling page with selenium in python , gives me just the bottom elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have page, but I need to scroll the page and get elements one-by-one.
I am using the following command:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

but this code scrolls bottom and gives me just last elements, but I need all of them above

I am using also this code this code, but result is the same. How I can extarct all of the elemnts, not top one or last ones

```
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)    
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    elll.append(el.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[contains(@class, "ProductItemWrapper")]'))  
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
        
    last_height = new_height      
elll=el.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[contains(@class, "ProductItemWrapper")]')
```

Does exist another way to scroll the page and scrape all the elemnts, not top or bottom ones ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.body.scrollHeight` gives the whole page scroll height. So, at once it is scrolled down to the bottom. So, use `window.scrollY` to get the current scroll position and scroll down only the viewport height `window.innerHeight` each time.

```
last_height = driver.execute_script("return window.scrollY")
elll=[]

while True:
    
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + window.innerHeight);")

    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)    
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return window.scrollY")
    elll.append(el.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[contains(@class, "ProductItemWrapper")]'))  
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
        
    last_height = new_height
```

Comment: Sure updated as well in the answer. Just wanted to point out the right JS properties to use. took the code from the question and made necessary changes. You're welcome.

Comment: When I want to extract from here text information it gives the error,  
`elll[0][0].text `  `StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)`  Is there problem of extraction?

Comment: Yes, make all the necessary operation on the elements when the elements are visible (inside the loop when you are in the scroll area). If you're doing the operations after the loop then you may have this error because you are at the bottom of the page some elements may not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll done page by page, not whole page height at once.
For example you can use this:
`driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)`